# How can I dynamically define a button's function

Tags: angular

I have created a child component called 'SideMenuComponent'. It dynamically creates menu buttons according to "items" input.

```
export class SideMenuComponent {
  @Input() items: IMenuNode[];
...
```

template

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
 <button (click)="item.click(item)">{{item.text}}</button>
</div>
```

And in the parent component, i created a menu array.

```
export class ParentComponent {
     public items: IMenuNode[] = [
        {
          text: "Help",
          icon: "help",
          click: () => { console.log("help me")}
        },
        {
          text: "Feedback",
          icon: "feedback",
        }
      ];
...
```

and used it in the template.

```
<sidemenucomponent-selector [items]="items"></sidemenucomponent-selector>
```

Buttons and their icons are displayed without a problem. However, click function does not work. When I click Help it does not print "help me"

```
click: () => { console.log("help")}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do the click events need to have completely different functionality or are they going to perform similarly?

Comment: @Cory Could you recreate the issue in a plunker? It worked fine for me when I tested your code.

Comment: I recreated it in a plunker. It worked. Now it works on my project, too. I did not change anything it may be some compile or build problem, I'm not sure. Sorry for taking your time and thank you very much.

Comment: Check the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298258/dynamic-click-function-angular2
and you will find your answer.