# Dynamic (click) function - Angular2

Tags: angular

I am having a little trouble with binding a dynamic function to a click event. Please see below:-

File 1

```
<title-bar [actions]='[{title: "Create A New Plan", link: "hello"}]' ></title-bar>
```

File 2

```
<div class="actions" *ngIf="actions">
    <a *ngFor="let action of actions" class="ui primary button" (click)="[action.link]()">{{action.title}}</a>
</div>
```

All of the code is working perfectly apart from when I am binding the action.link in the (click).

If I create the following button:-

```
<button (click)="hello()"></button>
```

It calls the hello() function as it should. but for some reason I am not able to get this to work dynamically.

Does anybody have a simple solution to this I may have over looked?

The function is calling a simple alert just for testing:-

```
public hello() {
    alert('test');
}
```

II have attempted to change the click event to the following but with no joy:-

```
(click)="action.link"
(click)="[action.link]()"
(click)="this[action.link]()"
```

I get the following errors respectively:-

```
No error, but not function called
inline template:3:2 caused by: ["hello"] is not a function
inline template:3:2 caused by: self.parentView.parentView.context[self.context.$implicit.link] is not a function
```

Any help with a push in the right direction will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>In the component you need</strike>

```
get self() { return this; }
```

and in the template

```
<a *ngFor="let action of actions" class="ui primary button"
  (click)="self[action.link]()">{{action.title}}</a>
```

Use

```
<a *ngFor="let action of actions" class="ui primary button"
  (click)="this[action.link]()">{{action.title}}</a>
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain and elaborate on the "get self() { return this; }" function?

Comment: With `(click)="[action.link]()"` you create an array with one item `action.link` and apply a function call (which is not expected to work). With `(click)="self[action.link]()"` you reference the property with the name from `action.link` of the object returned by `self` which is the components class instance (which I assumed is what you want). `this` is not supported in the template AFAIK, so `self` is a workaround to make `this` available.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, this work around works perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work :)

Comment: `this` is now available in the template to refer to the component class, so the self getter is no longer required

Comment: How would one pass arguments in the function call?

Comment: Like in TypeScript. Just pass it. Yoir question is not clear to me. Can you elaborate what you want to pass and for what purpose?

Comment: Upgrading to Angular 9 appears to break this solution. With previously working code, I now get the following error... ERROR TypeError: "ctx_r355[Button_r353.click] is not a function"

Comment: I just went back to your self example above and it now works in 9. I guess sometimes we have to go back a little to move forward? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I needed to do something similar with ngFor.
Accepted answer works but gave me a linting error: 'Call target is not callable'

There's another SO answer from Günter which helped me find a lint-error free solution : [Angular2 passing function as component input is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574759/angular2-passing-function-as-component-input-is-not-working)

**My component.ts**

```
this.myLinks = [
  {
    imgSrc: 'assets/a.png,
    clickFunction: this.aFn,
  },
  {
    imgSrc: 'assets/b.png,
    clickFunction: this.bFn,
  },
];


aFn() {
  console.log('function A');
}
bFn() {
  console.log('function B');
}
```

**My template.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let link of myLinks">
   <img
     [src]="link.imgSrc"
     (click)="link.clickFunction.apply(this)"
   />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me like this:

```
(click)=self[action.link]()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Component.ts

```
items = [
  {
    name: 'share',
    action: this.share
  },
  {
    name: 'report',
    action: this.report
  }
];

share() {}
report() {}
```

> Component.html

```
<el *ngFor="let i of items" (click)="i.action()"></el>
```