# Bind a function in Angular2+

Tags: angular, bind, ag-grid

I'm working with [AgGrid](https://www.ag-grid.com) and want to use a localisation.

I add `[localeTextFunc]="localeTextFunc"` in my  `<ag-grid-angular HERE></ag-grid-angular>`

In my ts file i have :

```
localeTextFunc(key, defaultValue) {
  console.log("key : ", key);
  console.log("defaultValue : ", defaultValue);
  console.log("this :", this);

  // need to use my translate service
  this.translate....
}
```

My problem is that `this` is undefined.
How can i bind `this` to my function ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 passing function as component input is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574759/angular2-passing-function-as-component-input-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use Arrow functions. Regular functions always use the scope of the object that called it(window, document, button etc.).

Arrow functions always use the object where it was defined as scope.

Therefore in your .ts file if you make your function like below, it should  work:

```
localeTextFunc=(key, defaultValue)=>{
  console.log("key : ", key);
  console.log("defaultValue : ", defaultValue);
  console.log("this :", this);

  // need to use my translate service
  this.translate....
}
```

Another solution is to do aomething like this:
`<ag-grid-angular [localeTextFunc]="localeTextFunc.bind(this)"></ag-grid-angular>`

However, I would recommend the first option.